# WPF: добавить элемент в ObservableCollection<T> через IEnumerable

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Такая дилемма: у меня есть эдакий "ItemsSource" в моем элементе управления. `DependencyProperty` типа `IEnumerable`. К нему привязан `ObservableCollection<T>`. Мне нужно извне добавлять/удалять элементы в привязанную коллекцию. При этом я не знаю, какая коллекция привязана, у меня есть доступ только к свойству элемента, а `IEnumerable` не подразумевает функций `Clear` или `Add`.

Что тут можно сделать?

Comment: Можно попробовать привести к `ICollection<T>`, если известен `T`, или даже сразу к `ObservableCollection<T>`. Так делают многие классы, работающие с WPF.

Comment: Ничего. Если вы объявили свойство типа `IEnumerable`, клиент имеет право записать туда любую реализацию, в том числе и не поддерживающую добавление элементов. Если вам нужна возможность добавления элементов – объявляйте тип, который это поддерживает, например `IList`.

Comment: А вообще посмотрите, например, как реализован `ItemsControl` – в нем реализовано ещё отдельное свойство `Items`. Ну и можете посмотреть как сделано в `DataGrid` – если к нему привязана коллекция, не позволяющая добавлять элементы, то этот функционал отключается, вы можете пройти и по этому пути

Comment: Да, возможно я не уточнил. У меня туда всегда будет передаваться `ObservableCollection`. Просто я не знаю тип элемента, поэтому и сделал общий `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @АндрейNOP. Поскольку `IEnumerable` не поддерживает изменение коллекции, я изменил тип свойства на `IList`. В моей ситуации это не повлекло дополнительных проблем.